# When using a function cases, I only get the curly bracket for the first line, how to resolve the error?

Tags: equations, cases, mathjax

I am using Overleaf to write a piecework function, and I know that in MathJax the function works, I write `\begin{cases}` `\end{cases}` and then separate the intervals with `\\`, but in Overleaf it gives me the curly bracket only for the first row, anything that is after `\\` is not in these brackets, although I put all the expression in `\begin` `\end` function. Can anybody help?  Also for additional info, maybe anyone knows an online platform, that works on MathJax, not on LaTeX? This is my code:

```
$ F(x)= 
\begin{cases} 
0, & x\leq 0 \textbf{ or } y\leq 0 \\ 
\frac{x^2y+xy^3}{2}, & \textbf{ if} 0\leq x,y \leq 1 \\ 
\frac{x^2+x}{2}, & \textbf{ kad } 0\leq x \leq 1, \; y \geq 1 \\ 
\frac{y+y^3}{2}, & \textbf{ if} x>1, 0\leq y \leq 1 \\ 
    1,& \textbf{ if } y \geq 1, x \geq 1 
    \end{cases}$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! First off, MathJax is not LaTeX, so things may (and they do) differ. Second, please show us a minimal example that reproduces the problem. WIthout seeing the code we can only guess

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "I put all the expression in `\begin` `\end` function."?

Comment: I am unable to replicate your issue on Overleaf as well as my local system. You must be doing something different. Can you supply a link to your project on Overleaf?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never ignore errors, you have

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$ F(x)= 
\begin{cases} 
0, & x\leq 0 \textbf{ or } y\leq 0 \\ 
\frac{x^2y+xy^3}{2}, & \textbf{ if} 0\leq x,y \leq 1 \\ 
\frac{x^2+x}{2}, & \textbf{ kad } 0\leq x \leq 1, \; y \geq 1 \\ 
\frac{y+y^3}{2}, & \textbf{ if} x>1, 0\leq y \leq 1 \\ 
    1,& \textbf{ if } y \geq 1, x \geq 1 
    \end{cases}$
\end{document}
```

which produces

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
l.7 0, &
         x\leq 0 \textbf{ or } y\leq 0 \\
?
```

You need to load the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$ F(x)= 
\begin{cases} 
0, & x\leq 0 \textbf{ or } y\leq 0 \\ 
\frac{x^2y+xy^3}{2}, & \textbf{ if} 0\leq x,y \leq 1 \\ 
\frac{x^2+x}{2}, & \textbf{ kad } 0\leq x \leq 1, \; y \geq 1 \\ 
\frac{y+y^3}{2}, & \textbf{ if} x>1, 0\leq y \leq 1 \\ 
    1,& \textbf{ if } y \geq 1, x \geq 1 
    \end{cases}$
\end{document}
```

tex never makes any attempt to make sensible typeset output after an error, the output is possibly useful for debugging but it not intended to be a usable display.

Answer (score 2):

(I am assuming you are going to use LaTeX)

The `cases` environment from `amsmath` uses `&` for the "left and right" parts of the definition (left being the function and right being the condition, usually) and `\\` to go to a new line.

For example the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
u(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
 \exp{x} & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\
 1       & \text{if } x < 0
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

yields

[image: cases]

Note the `\\` to end the line. You can of course have multiple lines.

Comment: I added my code, and it looks like yours, but Overleaf still presents it incorrectly. Any advice?

Comment: @user see my answer, your examples should always be _complete_ documents that show the problem, and also if you get an error, show the error not the typeset output.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating a little on David Carlisle's answer, LaTeX has  a `\cases` macro, not an environment, which can be used as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  f(x) =
  \cases{
  0&for $x \leq 0$,\cr
  e^{-1/x}&for $x > 0$.
  }
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

The syntax is not LaTeX like, e.g. line changes with `\cr` not `\\`, since the macro is essentially inherited from plain TeX.  Also the brace is too small (but can be improved by writing `\mathstrut` before each line) and the spacing is rather tight.  Because of LaTeX's internals, if you write `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}` then the `\cases` macro is invoked, but its argument is not interpreted correctly.  This makes the error message received somewhat opaque, i.e. there is no complaint about an undefined macro/environment but rather the misplaced alignment character error reported by David.

On the other hand, the `amsmath` package implements a good `cases` environment, as demonstrated by David's code, but to access it you need to load the package.